# サブドメインへのアクセスをURLそのまま、メインドメインへ転送する

Tags: apache, .htaccess

http://example.com/xxx/ へのアクセスを、ユーザー側の表示URLはそのままにサブドメイン http://xxx.example.com/
へ転送する方法を探しています。
レンタルサーバーでの制約で両ドメインのドキュメントルートにある.htaccessのみの設定で変更できると助かります。
策を知っている方がおりましたら、ご教示お願いします!

Comment: タイトルと本文で言ってることが逆のような気がしますが…リダイレクトではなく、ユーザーは自分がアクセスしたドメインをずっと見ているつもりで実際は別ドメインの内容が表示される、ということでしょうか。

Comment: 契約されているレンタルサーバーの設定次第なので、そちらのサポートに問いあわせることをお勧めします。ここで解決する為にひつような情報をレンタルサーバ会社から提供してもらえるなら最初からそちらに尋ねられた方が早いでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※既に解決していますが、コメントの指摘を反映しつつ  
質問を「レンタルサーバー上のエリアスの設定方法について」と推測して回答を整理します。

---

最初にサーバーの仕様をレンタルサーバーのサポートに確認して下さい。  
レンタルサーバー各社で仕様が異なります。

場合によってはユーザー側で自由に設定できなくても  
レンタルサーバー会社に作業依頼してエリアスを設定出来る事もあるかもしれません。

mod_rewrite、mod_proxyが使用可能な場合は  
foo.com上の.htaccessに記述する事でエリアスを設定できます。

```
RewriteRule ^/xxx/(.*)$ http://xxx.foo.com/$1 [P,QSA]
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.foo.com/
```

.  
タグにApatchが入ってるのでApatchの設定ファイルの記述も合わせて載せておきます。

転送先が違うサーバー上のファイルの場合

```
ProxyPass /xxx/ http://xxx.foo.com/
ProxyPassReverse /xxx/ http://xxx.foo.com/
```

転送先も同じサーバー上のファイルの場合

```
Alias /xxx/ [xxx.foo.com のディレクトリを指定]
```

尚、転送先が同じサーバー上のファイルであれば  
シンボリックリンクでも同様のことが出来ます。

Comment: 前者について調べてみましたが、`[QSA]`や`ProxyPassReverse`もつけたほうがいいかもしれません。 http://blog.livedoor.jp/techblog/archives/65151527.html

Comment: Pフラグはmod_proxyが有効になっている必要がありますがレンタルサーバではまず間違いなく有効になっていないでしょう。Aliasは.htaccessでは設定できません

Comment: ありがとうございます!
これで対策を打つことができました。
お力添えにとても感謝しています。

Comment: 指摘を受けて回答を修正致しました。

Comment: ProxyPassReverseも.htaccessでは設定できません。